# why emit not working inside socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to send an event to socket inside the socket for example

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit("connected", {msg: 1});

  socket.on('funcb', function (data) {
    console.log('funca sent following data');
    console.log(data); 
  });

  socket.on('funca', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('funcb', data);
  });


});
```

funca is called from client/browser and it try to call the funcb but func b not working any ideas?

Comment: You have emitted `funcb` before listening to `funcb`. try to move `socket.on('funcb'…` before `socket.on('funca'`

Comment: Might be the "emit" is just sending event back to client (browser) not socket itself, so it is unable to catch event 'funcb', I am catching funcb in the client (browser)

Comment: have you tried replacing `socket.on('funcb'` to `this.on('funcb'`

Answer (score 1):

To explain what @bolav said with code:

**Client side:**

```
  socket.emit("connected", {msg: 1});

  socket.on('funcb', function (data) {
    console.log('funcb from server sent following data');
    console.log(data); 
  });

  socket.on('funca', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('funcb', data);
  });
```

**Server Side:**

```
socket.on('funcb', function (data) {
console.log('funca from client side sent following data');
console.log(data);
socket.emit("funcb", data); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the "emit" is just sending event back to client (browser) not socket itself, so it is unable to catch event 'funcb'

Answer (score 0):

`socket.emit('funcb', data)` sent from the client will not invoke the `socket.on('funcb')` listener on the client. It will emit to the other side and invoke the `socket.on` listener on the server.

Comment: actually it will be invoke all who listens to `funcb` including the one who `emits` it. However `socket.broadcast.emit` will invoke all who listens to `funcb` except the one who emits it